# Microsoft Translator charges me 1000 characters for a 20 character translation

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator, machine-translation, azure-marketplace

Can someone explain why this is happening?  I'm using their TranslationContainer sample they've provided.

This strikes me as wrong; if I'm translating lots of small pieces of text I'm going to be changed per translation rather than against my quota of characters.

Can someone explain what's happening here

Comment: Do they have customer support? What's their position? This looks more like a billing issue to me, not a programming one.

Comment: Not really.  MS state that I am able to translate 2 million chars a month.  At present a 20 char request is taking 1000 chars from my quota.  It is entirely possible there is a default length on the translation text and I'm submitting 20 characters and 920 empty spaces.  I'd like to know 1)If this is correct 2)If there is a way of specifying how many characters I've submitted, 3)what the rules are around translations because I can't find them anywhere and they're not in the T&Cs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Microsoft Customer Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>As of today, this is how the Translator service usage is measured. The default transaction length is 1,000 characters.</s>

**EDIT 3/18/2012**: I reached out to the team and heard back: You are getting the proper number of characters per month, per subscription details, but the counter display isn't reliable at the moment. A fix is coming. I don't have an exact date for the fix.

**EDIT 5/17/2012**: Looks like this has been fixed. There's also a [blog post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsofttranslator/thread/f688573c-9832-4c7a-9470-5c98f6f7ad42) about real-time updates to remaining characters per month, as well as low-balance notifications:

Comment: Interesting. Is this specified somewhere public, or do the API users have to find out the hard way?

Comment: Is there any way of changing this default? It seems strange that they advertise the service based on characters translated when the amount of wasted characters (I sent a 20 character query and got charged for 1000 characters) can be quite high.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the counter display, not the actual # of characters being translated. See my updated answer.